# How can I send an alert or log in some way who has visited an item detail page? SP 21010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Newsletters are created via a form populated via a custom list row.
I have been asked if user/login can be captured on who opened/read the page.
Is this possible via an alert or workflow?

Answer (score 0):

If it's 2010, you should be able to pull a custom report under Web Analytics and it should show you who all visited the page.

Comment: Hello tiffy does that include their login name?